# Eclipse auto completion not working

Tags: java, eclipse

for some of variable like int,char, "no completion avaiable " is written. But for bitmap, string e.g. it is fine. I try to check all proposals from window>preferences>java>contentassists but after restarting eclipse "java type proposals" and "java non type proposals" are unchecked.I created new workspace, I reinstalled eclipse indigo. But non of them solves the problem.

Comment: Post your screenshot of Java Content Assist & Advanced configuration

Comment: http://imageupload.org/?d=BC61F2D61

Answer (score 2):

If you have a variable of type `int` or `char`, there are no completions possible as these are not Java object (but rather primitive types). `Bitmap` and `String` are a different story...